# Pip Wheel Package Installation Fail

Tags: python, azure, pip, python-wheel

I try to run `pip wheel azure-mgmt=0.20.1`, but whenever I run it I get following pip wheel error, which is very clear:

`error: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'build\\bdist.win32\\wheel\\azure_mgmt-0.20.0.data\\..'`

So my question is where or how I can find that path? I want to delete that existing file. I have been searching my local computer, searched for default path in Google, but still didn't find any solution.

Also is it possible to tell `pip wheel` to output full log? As you can see that full error path is not displayed. I'm using virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

We can see the description of virtual env at the [official python guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/#virtual-environment):

> To help manage external package dependencies, Azure Git deployment supports the creation of virtual environments.
>
> When Azure detects a requirements.txt in the root of the repository, it automatically creates a virtual environment named env. This only occurs on the first deployment, or during any deployment after the selected Python runtime has changed.

You can directly modify the dependencies and versions of them in `requirement.txt`, then deploy your python app to Azure Web App via git, Azure will update the python packages automatically. You can check the packages in the virtual env folder which path is `env\Lib\site-packages` in the root directory of your site. You can login on the kudu console of your site to check your files of you site online, the URL should be: `https://{your_site_name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` .

Additionally, according your description, it seems that you use the global python environment to run pip install command which may directly install packages in your global python environment. To install packages in your virtual env, you need to run the similar command  `env\scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt` in your root directory of your application. Please refer to [Web app development - Windows - command line](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/#web-app-development---windows---command-line) for more information.

Comment: This doesn't help much, because I wanted to have wheel version of each package. I know how to install packages with requirements.txt and I know how to deploy it to Azure. My problem is that when I try to package azure-mgmt with `pip wheel` it says as I described in my question and I have tried to delete and reinstall the whole package, but still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?

I tried `pip wheel azure-mgmt` and that installed -0.20.1 for me.

The directory for mine is /Users/me/wheelhouse, so you could look there. I found that in the initial log of the build.

Comment: Yes I have uninstalled and reinstalled it and still doesn't work. If that PATH points to the wheelhouse directory in the project then I know where it is located, but still it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Amir,
One option is that you could generate the `requirement.txt` file and remove your virtual environment if you used Visual studio to develop your application. Then you can add a new virtual environment for your project and install all packages from `requirement.txt` file.  Or after removed your virtual environment, you can try `pip wheel azure-mgmt` command.

And another option is that you can follow this similar issue：https://vilimpoc.org/blog/2014/01/18/time-robbing-python-errors/ 
The blogger modified the `LOCALAPPDATA` path to resolve this issue. Please try it.